# Vs Code browser not working while using Django

Tags: django, visual-studio-code, web-applications

I am trying to test the frontend of a Django project and want to use the VS code simple browser to open the local hosted site. In doing so it gives me no output(while it works perfectly on chrome) and the terminal show me this output

`"GET /1?vscodeBrowserReqId=1676305382720 HTTP/1.1" 200 176`

I haven't found anything related to this issue on the net and was wondering if it a Django problem or VS code

Answer (score 0):

By default, Django sets `X-Frame-Options` to `DENY`, which means that your site cannot be embedded in an iframe. This why you're not seeing any output in the VS Code simple browser.

To resolve this issue, you can update the `X-Frame-Options` header in your Django project settings. In your `settings.py` file, you can add the following line:

```bash
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'
```

This will allow your site to be embedded in iframes from the same origin.

Alternatively, you can remove `django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware` from your `settings.py`.

Refer this doc for more information around this middleware: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/clickjacking/

[image: working example after removing XFrameOptionsMiddleware]